# Salesforce Report Filter Logic

Tags: custom-reports

I just want to know the Salesforce report filter logic

I tried this logic and it throws an error. How to fix this?

```
1 AND 2 AND (3 OR 4 OR 5 OR 6 OR 7 OR 8 OR 9 OR 10 OR 11 OR 12)

((1 AND 2) AND (3 OR 4 OR 5 OR 6 OR 7 OR 8 OR 9 OR 10 OR 11 OR 12))

(1 AND 2) AND (3 OR 4 OR 5 OR 6 OR 7 OR 8 OR 9 OR 10 OR 11 OR 12)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The error message is "Some filter conditions are defined but not referenced in your filter logic." @JitenderPadda

Comment: I think you might have more filters which you have not defined in this logic. Can you post some screenshots ?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to respect the format:

- Only one space
- no space between bracket and filter number

I tried it out, and it seems to work - be sure to reference all filter criteria that you created.
[image]